# Table (cell) height vs. font-size

Tags: css, html-table, font-size

My table cells have a font-size of 9pt.  Within these table cells there is either a spacer image or text.  If it's a spacer image I just want the height of the table, the height of the spacer image (2px in this case).  Code below:

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" class="foo">   
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">     
            <td width="100%" colspan="4" class="foo">
                <img width="0" height="1" alt="" src="spacer.gif">
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" class="foo">   
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">     
            <td width="100%" colspan="4" class="foo">
                bar <span>barbar</span>
            </td>   
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As of right now, whether it's text or a spacer image the height of the cell is 9pt.  And if this wasn't bad enough, I CANNOT change the markup.  What you see is what I get.

Comment: is there a certain reason why you don't use CSS to style your table instead of HTML attributes? If not, I would strongly recommend it to you! :)

Comment: first, where does it say it is 9pt? do you DO have a stylesheet or some other code you have not shown here? Furthermore, you don't need to apply 100% to the <td> tags if there is only one per row and the whole table is set to 100% already. But it would be much easier to help if you could show some more code :)

Comment: I cannot change the markup as I've said in my original post.  No matter how much I want to, I am unable to.  I've since removed all styling and the table cell and the image spacer is still not collapsing.

If it were me, I would just take out the image spacer.  Solves all my issues, but I can't change the markup.

Comment: ok, I won't ask you now why you can't change the markup. However, you did not answer: do you use a stylesheet separately? Why is the font-size set to 9pt? Because you cannot see from the code you have posted that it is 9pt... where is it set?

Comment: The CSS has been stripped so the 9pt setting on the font-size doesn't matter.  Your previous comments on using CSS instead of attributes dawned on me.  This page I'm editing uses HTML5 and those attributes are deprecated, yielding unpredictable results in rendering.

Comment: I've tried this markup in HTML4 vs. HTML5 and sure enough, HTML4 had what I wanted.  The markup was the issue. Thank you.

Even I don't even ask why I can't change the markup. :P
Thanks again.

Comment: Submit an answer so I can accept? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, cpara :)

This is not best practice, but if you really cannot change your HTML, you could still use a stylesheet. If the styles in the stylesheet do not overwrite the HTML styles, you can also try to add !important (like `width:100% !important;`) to any style in your stylesheet...

Well, if the 9pt font-size is not set anywhere but the text is rendered to 9pt, it can be that you do use a separate stylesheet and the 9pt are set in either the div or the body, or your browser's standard font-size (if not font-size is set) is set to 9pt...

But great, if the answer was finally closer than thought and it works now for you :)